# This should be a typo error - minor

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling, privileges-page

From this link ( https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties )

*SECTION*: **When does a bounty expire?**

the highlighted phrase needs to be examined for probable typo error.

...half the bounty value **will be automatically be awarded** to the top voted answer posted after the bounty start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All we can do is edit it on the [Meta privileges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties), but we have to wait for the devs to push out the changes at some point before they go live on other sites. I think there are still some other changes pending in the Meta wikis that need pushed out as well.

Answer (score 2):

The [privilege page on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties), which is the one used as master for the other sites, is correct.

> If you do not award the bounty within 24 hours of the bounty period ending, half the bounty value will be automatically awarded to the top voted answer posted after the bounty start, provided it has a score of at least 2.

As far as I know, the master page is not automatically pushed to the other sites; somebody needs to do it.